# Can this question be taken off hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

Can this question be taken off hold please?

I have edited the question to add code.

[toggle() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487754/toggle-not-working)

Comment: As you have just edited your question, it will now be reviewed by those traversing the reopen queue. There is no need to bring up every single closed question to Meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is re-opened by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49487754/timeline#history_87a06261-97a7-4d29-ba3d-bec9d638a9b8) with his moderator powers. If that didn't happen your question would have been handled in the re-open queue but that [outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/19243352) needs patience and the outcome might not be what you hope for...

I would personally have waited for the re-open review to be finished before running to meta but that is just me.

Comment: That's a hard sale, the request was honored in almost no time ;) Its hard to argue against very effective results achieved with almost no effort.

Answer (score 7):

> I have edited the question to add code.

You really should know, especially after having asked over 200 (!) questions, that your question must include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the get-go.

Don't post a story about your code, post your code. Then your question has a lot less of a chance of getting closed.